# Understanding the definition of a field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

So $$(F,+,*) $$is a field iff $$(F,+)\quad \text{and}\quad (F\setminus \{0\},*)$$ are abelian goups.
$F\setminus \{0\}$ denotes F without the member zero.

So $$(F,+)$$ is sure a commutative group :

Identity exists which is $0$

Associativity exists

Commutative.

Inverse exists such that $-a+a=0$

is closed under multiplication.

But when we come to $(F\setminus \{0\},*)$

I couldnt find the inverse for all $a$ which is a member of $F$
Find me a number $b$ such that $a*b=0$ other than $0$?

So how come $(F\setminus \{0\},*)$ is a commutative/abelian group?

Comment: its a definition. A condition. There's no reason 'why' it is a commutative group. It is just defined to be that way

Comment: Then since real numbers are a field, find a $b$ in real numbers such that for any $a$ $a*b=0$ other than $0$. We can't find right? So I couldnt get it. Real numbers without $0$ (an example of a field) isn't a abelian group under multiplication.

Comment: There's a seperate identity element for $(F,+)$ and for $(F,*)$. in the case $F=\mathbb{R}$, the identity element for $+$ is $0$, while the identity element for $*$ is $1$. So you shouldnt look for $b$ s.t. $a*b=0$, but $b$ s.t. $a*b=1$, so you'll find $b=1/a$.

Comment: I'm not looking for the identity element I'm looking for the inverse element for $*$

Comment: Well either way, the inverse for $*$ of $a$ is $1/a$. So concretely, the inverse for say $\pi$ is $1/\pi$

Comment: @Xenidia Yes, but your problem is that you have the wrong identity element  in mind, so you're not recognizing what inverses are in this context. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: Tangentially, your definition of field is incomplete as you need distributive law too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating two different operations. Note that the group operation in $(F\setminus \{0\}, *)$ is multiplication, **not** addition! You are correct that the reals without zero are not an abelian group *under addition*, but they are an abelian group *under multiplication*.

Put another way: when you go looking for inverses in $(F\setminus \{0\}, *)$, you're trying to multiply to $1$, not $0$. For example, in the reals without zero, the inverse of $3$ is ${1\over 3}$ - the "identity" element is $1$, and $3\cdot {1\over 3}=1$.

Note that this means that the multiplicative group of a field is *not* a subgroup of the additive group of the field!

Comment: Okay I got it, This group definition below got me confused :